# Splunk Query Recommendation

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-dashboard, splunk-sdk

I have below log from my application:

```
BookData, {
id: 12312
}, appID : 'APP1', Relation_ID : asdas-12312
host = aws@asd. sourcetype=service_name
```

The entire log above is in the form of a single String. I want to create a table with the no. of times an *appID* has hit the service. i.e. I want to count the no. of events and group them by appID.

Basically, something like:

```
appID Count
APP1    23
APP2    25
APP3    100
```

I tried with below query, but it is not working. It is giving as 0 records found.

```
index=my_index sourcetype=service_name * | table appID Count | addColTotals labelfield=appID label="appID" count
```

As per my understanding, above query is not working because *appID* is not a label, but in that case, how do I go about forming the query with my desired result.

Answer (score 2):

The query doesn't work in part because there is no Count field for the `table` command to display and no count field for the `addcoltotals` command to add to the results.  To get a count you must tell Splunk to count fields by using the `stats`, `eventstats`, `streamstats`, or `timechart` command.

Try this:

```
index=my_index sourcetype=service_name
| stats count as Count by appID
```